# Group rows in Excel and concatenate values from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a way in Excel 2007 to group repeating rows (rows with the same value in one column) and concatenate the values from another column?

E.g.,

```
COL1  COL2

aaa     X
aaa     Y
```

Desired:

```
COL1  COL2

aaa    X,Y
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a macro and then execute that macro whenever you need to.  If you are unfamiliar with how to create macros check out [**Creating VBA Macros**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd553655%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

**Try this:**

```vb
Sub combineValues()
    Dim dic As Dictionary
    Dim key, val, i, p, k
    Set dic = New Dictionary
    For i = 1 To Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        key = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        val = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
        If dic.Exists(key) Then
            dic.Item(key) = dic.Item(key) & ", " & val
        Else
            dic.Add key, val
        End If
    Next
    p = 1
    For Each k In dic.Keys
        Worksheets(2).Cells(p, 1) = k
        Worksheets(2).Cells(p, 2) = dic.Item(k)
        p = p + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that you'll have to include "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in "Reference" in order to use `Dictionary`.

**Tested with following [Sheet 1]:**

```
1   value 1
2   value 2
3   value 3
1   value 4
1   value 5
3   value 6
3   value 7
2   value 8
1   value 9
2   value 10
2   value 11
2   value 12
```

**Results in following [Sheet 2]:**

```
1   value 1, value 4, value 5, value 9
2   value 2, value 8, value 10, value 11, value 12
3   value 3, value 6, value 7
```

Comment: In order for this to work you will have to enable Microsoft scripting runtime. In the VBA editor: Tools menu->Referenses->Tick Microsoft scripting runtime and save